# Outlook shows rectangles instead of li bullet lists

Tags: html, css, utf-8, outlook, newsletter

I'm sendig a newsletter with html and php, and I have a problem with ul > lis
instead of bullets rectangles are shown

The saved html from Outlook shows that the html lists are converted to spans:

```
<span style="font-size:10.0pt;
      font-family:Symbol;mso-fareast-font-family:Symbol;mso-bidi-font-family:
      Symbol"><span style="mso-list:Ignore">·<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      </span></span></span>
```

Any solutions for that ?

Comment: Tip: If you want HTML email to be rendered well by Outlook, the best bet is to compose a template with Outlook. But even that is not a guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from **Digital_Frankenstein** will work, though it's a bit verbose.

Alternatively, using `list-style-type: disc;` is supported just fine in Outlook.

```
<ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style-type: disc;">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

This is the method I prefer; it's semantic and accessible. You have to ensure the list is spacing correctly, though, as different email clients do different things by default. I typically go with something like this:

```
<ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0; list-style-type: disc;">
  <li style="margin: 0 0 0 15px;">One</li>
  <li style="margin: 0 0 0 15px;">Two</li>
  <li style="margin: 0 0 0 15px;">Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Potentially just a rendering difference between rendering engines.

`&bull;` can be used to mimic bullet points. 
Best way to use it is to put this all in a table and use `&bull;` and rows to separate your points.

Like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:xxx; font-size:xxx;">&bull;</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:xxx; font-size:xxx;">&bull;</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="color:xxx; font-size:xxx;">&bull;</td>
    <td>Text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```